# Android subscriptions - get reliable introductory price information

Tags: android, android-billing, in-app-subscription, android-inapp-purchase, play-billing-library

I have an subscription item with an introductory price for 1 cycle. I am able to fetch this price within the app via the [getIntroductoryPrice()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/SkuDetails.html#getIntroductoryPrice()) method. Once a purchase has been done I am having trouble getting what exact price was paid for the subscription on the server side. In particular:

- On the app side, the "introductory price" info I get from the call above seems to be the same even if the user does not qualify (e.g. he is changing subscription from a full price one). Is there a way to see what price the user actually payed (from the app or server side?)
- On the server side, when I request the purchase receipt from the server I get information about the normal price, nothing on the introductory price nor what the user actually payed.

Is there any way for me to get reliable information on how much the user actually payed for subscriptions that include an introductory period?

Comment: Have you solved this problem yet ?